# Refresh a comboBox with newly Insert/Update in SQL database - Java

Tags: java, sql, combobox, refresh

the comboBox generates the info from SQL to begin with and I select one to make an Update to or just Insert new

Once all textFields are filled out there are 2 buttons to click which call methods that actually Insert or Update (Click to Insert, Click to Update buttons)

Once Clicked & info is added in SQL database, how do I refresh the comboBox with the information that was just added/changed?

Ive tried comboBox.UpdateUI() > nothing
Ive tried comboBox.setSelectedItem(variable) >  nothing

The language is Java and I am using Swing / WindowBuilder

Answer (score 0):

> Ive tried comboBox.UpdateUI()

Don't use the updateUI() method. That is invoked by the Swing on a LAF change.

> Once Clicked & info is added in SQL database, how do I refresh the comboBox with the information that was just added/changed?

You need to update the model of the combo box. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for an example that updates the ListModel on a button click. The example is for a JList but the concept of updating a model is the same for a JComboBox.